# Alter variable by an amount in real time seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, calculation

I have a float value that I would like to decrease by 10.f per second; for example

```
floatx - 10f * 'second'
```

How can I get real time seconds or another form of time in unity?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/time-time-or-time-deltatime.495010/

Comment: "How can I recall the seconds or another time in unity?" - What does this mean?

Comment: I want to create a portion of time, which can be seconds, minutes, hours or other. So as to trigger an event for the time frame created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be in Update:

```
var -= 10.f * Time.deltaTime;
```

or, if the variable you are modifying is going to be affecting the movement of a physics object, then in fixedUpdate:

```
var -= 10.f * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

or if you alter your deltaTime for any reason (such as to create a slow motion effect) and you want this to happen in real time seconds regardless of this

```
// in update
var -= 10.f * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
```

or if it's altering something about a physics object

```
// in fixedUpdate
var -= 10.f * Time.fixedUnscaledDeltaTime
```

All these will reduce your variable by 10 per second

Comment: so Time.unscaledDeltaTime; and Time.fixedUnscaledDeltaTime do they indicate real seconds and are they equal among them?

Comment: The best to use would probably be `Time.deltaTime`. You only need to use `unscaledDeltaTime` if you *explicitly* alter the timestep somewhere else in your program and you only need to use `fixedDeltaTime` if the variable you are changing is related to the movement of a physics object. (This is because you should always modify physics objects in fixedUpdate)

Basically, to indicate real seconds use `Time.deltaTime`